# Using a smaller off-screen buffer for rendering

Tags: rendering, double-buffering

I am seeing this in most of the game codes I read and tutorial videos I watch. When using double buffering in rendering, they use a smaller sized off-screen buffer, then just scale it up when drawing onto the screen. Why is this so? Is there any advantages and/or disadvantages when using this technique?

Answer (score 1):

This technique is called ***MRT***'S or Multiple Render Targets, and employs the use of additional ***Framebuffers***.

---

### Why is this used?

Because when wanting to achieve certain screen space effects, whether it is screen space lighting or ambient occlusion, it is quite efficient to store certain scene parameters ***as textures***. Imagine a scene with hundreds of lights and thousands of objects. It is quite possible that many lights won't affect the final color of some of those objects, and yet they would be processed anyways within the lighting calculations for those objects. Instead, in the case of deferred shading the scene is encoded into a series of textures limited to what is actually visible in the viewport, then decoded and processed in a separate pass, reducing the rendering time quite significantly by just performing lighting calculations on each pixel of the viewport.

This isn't just useful for deferred shading, it is also a key choice for a wide range of other rendering techniques, such as shadow calculations.

### Why vary the size?

Certain effects, such as screen space ambient occlusion or bloom also apply visual effects to the screen from the camera's perspective. However, these effects may undergo a series of blurring passes like box blurring or gaussian blurring. These blurring passes will take **longer** based on the **size** of the screen.

Since the end goal of some of these techniques is a blurred texture (blurring out high frequency information), a smaller texture would not only aid in losing some of that information, but would also allow the blurring pass to finish much more quickly.

Comment: But, may I ask, why is it also used in small, simple 2D games as well? The ones that doesn't require intensive processing (Just drawing sprites)?

Comment: It can be used for the same reasons really. At the end of the day both 2D and 3D games have to ultimately render onto a 2D screen. Screen space effects are screen space effects after all.

Rendering to a smaller framebuffer just means faster operations at the expense of a less detailed visual effect, however sometimes that doesn't matter and corners can be cut.

Comment: -1; This answer convolves many aspects of rendering that are actually independent, none of which need apply to using an intermediate render target that's smaller than the output. For example, the technique is definitely *not* called MRT. You can use MRT with output-sized targets, or non-MRT with smaller targets; they're completely independent. You also usually *can't* use MRT with multiple frame buffers; usually you only get access to one at a time.

Comment: I never implied multiple parallel framebuffer rendering,  and you can output to multiple textures at a time while bound to a single frame buffer. General questions get general answers.